# Utilise Netsh Wlan in WIn PE 4.0

Tags: wifi, sccm-2012, windows-pe

We have been working with unattended domain joins using SCCM 2012. We used to use a command line step in the OSD to join the machine to the local wireless network prior to domain join.
The syntax used was *netsh wlan connect [localwirelessnetwork*]
This would then allow us to connect wirelessly to the domain. However in PE 4.0 the wlan functions of netsh are not available for use.
I have read the instructions [here](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/158834-how-to-use-the-wireless-function-under-winpe40/) and  [here](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/162453-winpe-40-enable-wireless-support/) and many others but no-one seems to have a complete solution for this.

I've managed to import all the .dll  and dll.mui files correctly as explained in the second link and wlan is showing up but when I try to execute a command using it it complains that wlansvc is not started. If I try to do a Net start wlansvc it complains that it is not recognised.

Has anyone managed to include the wlan functionality in Win PE 4.0 or worked out another way around this? Maybe using Powershell would be an option but I haven't been able to work out a way to implement that, there's nothing in what I've read that indicates there is the ability to do this, most Powershell cmdlets simply reference netsh.

If anyone has any ideas, solutions, pointers it would be most appreciated.

Comment: not sure if this would be a good use of DJOIN this is a process of joing a device while its offline.  Not sure how this would intereact with sccm 2012 since I don't use it for deployment anymore.

Comment: Are the clients on the wired network when running OSD? Or is this from a usb drive?

Comment: @MDMoore313 It is from a USB drive. If it's over a wired network this issue doesn't occur as we don't need to join the wireless to domain join. What situation are you using it in?

Answer (score 1):

Typically we'll use LAN, in some situations we have to use USB though, haven't joined to the domain on the USB builds as they were 100% offline (I think that was MS' recommendation or a sccm requirement, I can't remember).

What about opening a powershell prompt and trying to start the service via cmdlet? So it would be something like

`$(Get-Service | where name -eq wlansvc).Start`

that will for sure tell you if it's there (and make sure you're error is not just because `net start` is acting up), and also in 7 the name of the service is `wlansvc` and not `wlancgf`, was that a typo or is this different in WinPE 4.0?

Comment: It was a typo, I've corrected it thanks. I've been looking at Djoin and that might just be what we're after. It involves a bit of work beforehand but that's no big deal. I'll give the powershell trick a go but I think that Windows PE doesn't include the wireless networking components